# How to prevent Visual Studio from formatting specific code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I type the code below:

```
if (rows == 0) break;
```

and when I add the semicolon at the end, VS springs into action and converts it to:

```
if (rows == 0) 
    break;
```

Same thing happens with `if (rows = 0) return;` and some other constructs.

How can I prevent VS from formatting this specific code interaction without messing with all the other niceties that it provides?  I looked in Tools/Options/Text Editor/C#/Code Style/Formatting, but don't see anything obvious.

Comment: Have you tried turning off 'Pretty listing (reformatting) of code' in Text Editor?

Comment: I think you want this setting, `csharp_preserve_single_line_blocks = true`. It looks like it can be configured via the EditorConfig file. [Code style rule options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/code-style-rule-options?view=vs-2019)

Comment: It's actually `csharp_preserve_single_line_statements = true`. I tried them both and that's the one that affects this specific case.

Comment: I agree with Olivier Rogier, he has pointed you in the right direction. In addition, this option `Automatically format statement on;` also affects the format statement in this scenario(Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting > General), but please note, this option works when the `Leave statements and member declarations on the same line` option is unchecked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **enable** the VS option in main menu:

> Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code style > Formatting > Wrapping >
>
> *Leave statements and member declarations on the same line*

[image]

English version of same options dialog (VS2017 version):

[image]

Answer (score 8):

you add pragam waning disable settings, so when you do Ctr+K+D it will not format or whatever shortcut keys you may be using to format.

```
#pragma warning disable format
public class Item
{
      public string Prop1 { get; set; } 
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
} 
#pragma warning disable format
```

Comment: This is a great answer to the question's title that protects specific code against reformatting, but it sounds like OP wants to control that based on the particular formatting operation, not particular code blocks.

Comment: instead of the second "#pragma warning disable format" should be "#pragma warning restore format"